# Getting parent tr element from child element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table structure in my code

```
<tr>
  <td>Text 1 </td>
  <td>Text 2 </td>
  <td> <span class="edit" onclick="EditAccountInfo(id1)" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text 1 </td>
  <td>Text 2 </td>
  <td> <span class="edit" onclick="EditAccountInfo(id2)" /> </td>
</tr>
```

On clicking the span in the `<td>`, I want to highlight the selected row (`<tr>`). I am using the following code in the javascript function

```
function EditAccountInfo(id)
{
  $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "red");
}
```

I am not getting any errors and `$(this).closest('tr')` returns a valid object, but the background color style is not getting applied to the `<tr>`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this)` is the `window` object, not the clicked element. What's the `id` argument?

Comment: change to `EditAccountInfo(this)` instead of `EditAccountInfo(id1)`?

Comment: @David It is basically the ids identifying different rows

Comment: Really? Because neither of your rows have an `id` (of any kind).

Comment: @David I just pasted the minimal code here. Actually the table is being generated using a for each loop from a model object. So the actual code is something like onclick="EditAccountInfo('@Model.Account.Id')" . Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#my-table').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('backgroundColor','red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the `window` because you're using inline event handlers. I would recommend a more unobtrusive approach:

```
<span class="edit" data-account-id="id1" />
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = $(this).data('account-id');
    //...
});
```

Comment: You can also pass `this` as an argument in the `onclick` attribute. Also, if you are using a delegated event handler, don't use `.data()` to get information off newly added DOM elements, the data won't be there because jQuery only makes `data-*` attributes avaialble via `.data()` on page-load. Use `.attr('data-account-id')` instead, which will read the attribute in real-time rather than out of cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css("background","red");
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll notice the use of jQuery methods being used in the question? So it's safe to say he's already using jQuery. Though it's being used badly.

Comment: I wanted to tell him not to use javascript function, but jquery click function.